# How do I send http authorization header in GET request in drupal?

Tags: routes, users

How do I send http Authorization header in http GET request in drupal ?

Every things else works except the authorization part.

My custom module code:

```
/*
 *Implements hook_menu
 */
function mymodule_menu() {

$items['demo'] = array(
    'title' => 'Demo API integration with Drupal 7',
    'page callback' => 'demo_page',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    );
return $items;
}

//page callback
function demo_page() {

$options = array(
  'method' => 'GET',
  'data' => '',
  'timeout' => 15,
  'headers' => array('Accept' => 'application/json',
                    'Authorization' => 'Basic SomeKey23412lkjdfadjfadfasd'),
);

$result = drupal_http_request('https://api.examlesite.com/test/', $options);
var_dump($result);
drupal_set_message("Result is processing");
return "hello world";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add basic authorization to url to access http basic protected address.

```
  // http auth
  $remote_url = 'http://uname:pw1234@example.com/service/node';
```